# How to delete only certain rows after DB data update with Logstash and Elasticsearch

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have some rows I need to insert rows and delete them if they change.

I'm pushing inside from Oracle rows done in this way:

- request number (key)
- request status (number)
- last_update (time)

If the request is status 1 (PENDING REQUEST), I have to index it.
If the request is status 10 (OK REQUEST), I have to skip it.

After, I have to analyze the requests:
If request goes from PENDING to OK, I have to delete it.
If request stays in PENDING, I have to keep it into ELK stack.

I think I can use the upsert function but I don't know exactly how to manage the situation. Can someone help me?